# Finding nodes with a path less than x within a network

Tags: python

I generated a graph with networkx that has multiple subgraphs within. I want to find nodes with the smaller subgraph and delete them from my original graph, so that my network is more visually pleasing. I've tried this with the following code, if G is my graph:

```
all_comb_nodes = combinations(list(G.nodes()), 2)

small_paths = []

for source, target in combinations(list(G.nodes()), 2):
    paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source = source, target = target, cutoff=4)
    small_paths.append(paths)
```

However I get this as my `small_path` output:

```
[<generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x7fe0492e4660>,
 <generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x7fe0492e46d0>,
 <generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x7fe0492e4820>,
 <generator object _all_simple_paths_graph at 0x7fe0492e4890>,etc]
```

any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: `all_simple_paths` seems to return an iterator that you need to iterate over to get any results

Comment: Try `paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, ...))` to create lists from those generator objects